# Keep the duplicated values only - Vectors C++

Tags: c++, vector

Assume I have a vector with the following elements {1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4}
I want to write a program with c++ code to remove the unique values and keep only the duplicated once. So the end result will be something like this {1,3}.

So far this is what I've done, but it takes a lot of time,
Is there any way this can be more efficient,

```
vector <int> g1 = {1,1,2,3,3,4}
vector <int> g2;

for(int i = 0; i < g1.size(); i++)
{
  if(count(g1.begin(), g1.end(), g1[i]) > 1)
    g2.push_back(g1[i]);

}

v.erase(std::unique(g2.begin(), g2.end()), g2.end());

for(int i = 0; i < g2.size(); i++)
{
  cout << g2[i];
}
```

Comment: Will the input vector always be sorted? If not, do you only want to check for duplicates adjacent to each other, or anywhere in the vector?

Comment: @BoBTFish Thank you for your reply, no it won't be sorted, and no the duplicates won't be adjacent to each other

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to keep only duplicates efficiently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550229/how-to-keep-only-duplicates-efficiently)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My approach is to create an `<algorithm>`-style template, and use an `unordered_map` to do the counting. This means you only iterate over the input list once, and the time complexity is `O(n)`. It does use `O(n)` extra memory though, and isn't particularly cache-friendly. Also this does assume that the type in the input is hashable.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <unordered_map>

template <typename InputIt, typename OutputIt>
OutputIt copy_duplicates(
        InputIt  first,
        InputIt  last,
        OutputIt d_first)
{
    std::unordered_map<typename std::iterator_traits<InputIt>::value_type,
                       std::size_t> seen;
    for ( ; first != last; ++first) {
        if ( 2 == ++seen[*first] ) {
            // only output on the second time of seeing a value
            *d_first = *first;
            ++d_first;
        }
    }
    return d_first;
}

int main()
{
    int i[] = {1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 5}; // print 1, 3,
    //                  ^     ^
    copy_duplicates(std::begin(i), std::end(i),
                    std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ", "));
}
```

This can output to any kind of iterator. [There are special iterators you can use that when written to will insert the value into a container.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter)

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked great !
Can you tell me what to do if want to return a vector with the values instead of printing them ?

Comment: @MohamedAbdelAziz - Now it sounds like you want someone to do your homework for you. You should figure that one out for yourself. It's not hard. :-)

Comment: @MohamedAbdelAziz I didn't give the code, but I gave a strong hint at the end!

Comment: I wrote a version that benchmarks the fastest of all the versions here. But it's O(n log n). I wonder how big the n has to be to swamp all the other stuff.

Comment: I have no found a crossover point. In fact, there's something about this algorithm that causes it to exhibit _n log n_ performance for very large n: https://pastebin.com/EWNTUkdf

Comment: @Omnifarious, even though this is `O(N)`, the constant is going to be huge due to the heavy lifting that is done in the `unordered_map`. Furthermore, lookup complexity for the hash map s going to depend heavily on the way the hash map is parameterized. Depending on the number of buckets, lookup complexity can be `O(N)` in itself in the extreme case (only one bucket).

Answer (score 4):

Here's a way that's a little more cache friendly than `unordered_map` answer, but is O(n log n) instead of O(n), though it does not use any extra memory and does no allocations. Additionally, the overall multiplier is probably higher, in spite of it's cache friendliness.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

void only_distinct_duplicates(::std::vector<int> &v)
{
    ::std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    auto output = v.begin();
    auto test = v.begin();
    auto run_start = v.begin();
    auto const end = v.end();
    for (auto test = v.begin(); test != end; ++test) {
       if (*test == *run_start) {
           if ((test - run_start) == 1) {
              *output = *run_start;
              ++output;
           }
       } else {
           run_start = test;
       }
    }
    v.erase(output, end);
}
```

I've tested this, and it works. If you want a generic version that should work on any type that vector can store:

```
template <typename T>
void only_distinct_duplicates(::std::vector<T> &v)
{
    ::std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    auto output = v.begin();
    auto test = v.begin();
    auto run_start = v.begin();
    auto const end = v.end();
    for (auto test = v.begin(); test != end; ++test) {
       if (*test != *run_start) {
           if ((test - run_start) > 1) {
              ::std::swap(*output, *run_start);
              ++output;
           }
           run_start = test;
       }
    }
    if ((end - run_start) > 1) {
        ::std::swap(*output, *run_start);
        ++output;
    }
    v.erase(output, end);
}
```

Comment: For smaller n, this actually runs a **LOT** faster than the accepted answer. At some point the accepted answer should be faster. But for n <= 50 (at least) it's a lot slower. My guess is that the crossover point might be in the 10s or 100s of thousands for integers. It might be higher for more complex types.

Comment: I think the accepted answer will never get faster, because it will start exhibiting `O(N^2)` behaviour due to the way the hash map is laid out in memory. Btw, I've slightly modified your implementation such that the first iteration through the loop already does useful work. Performance wise it is the same, but maybe simpler? See: https://godbolt.org/z/w5keYB

Comment: @TonvandenHeuvel - Yeah, yours will only be the tiniest bit faster, maybe, and that'll only even be possibly noticeable on very small lists. But, I do agree that it's probably easier to understand. I need to get better about using `<algorithm>` instead of raw loops most of the time. You should use `::std::move(*first)` though to make sure it still works for vectors of things that are moveable but not copyable.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the input vector is not sorted, the following will work and is generalized to support any vector with element type T. It will be more efficient than the other solutions proposed so far.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
void erase_unique_and_duplicates(std::vector<T>& v)
{
  auto first{v.begin()};
  std::sort(first, v.end());
  while (first != v.end()) {
    auto last{std::find_if(first, v.end(), [&](int i) { return i != *first; })};
    if (last - first > 1) {
      first = v.erase(first + 1, last);
    }
    else {
      first = v.erase(first);
    }
  }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 4};
  erase_unique_and_duplicates(v);

  // The following will print '2 3 4'.
  for (int i : v) {
    std::cout << i << ' ';
  }
  std::cout << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am pretty sure that erasing something in the middle of an `std::vector` is not efficient.

Comment: It will be more efficient than the `unordered_map` approach. There are no memory allocations here. I will benchmark this, now I'm curious :)

Comment: @TonvandenHeuvel By what measure? Mine has lower time complexity, but the allocation and caching effects will be rather unpredictable. I think this will depend hugely on the size and amount of repetition in the input set. It is a nice approach though, and there isn't enough in the question to say which will be a better solution for the asker.

Comment: @BoBTFish, your interface prohibits an efficient usage, since it will always copy. In the worst case, it will have to allocate as much memory as in the input vector. Using a naive approach with a `back_inserter` on an empty vector will have to reallocate multiple times worst case.

Comment: See: http://quick-bench.com/6XR8-tiDIqezQK0U4QufMdsOgdo

The benchmark is unfair in the sense that I have to clear the output vector in the `unordered_map` approach. To make up for it, I allocate `v` in the hot loop in my case :P

Comment: @TonvandenHeuvel - My version is the fastest for a tiny list. ;-) - http://quick-bench.com/6NW3KCqIKZENpM1W-2_I8rvFLSo . And for larger lists, the difference is even greater: http://quick-bench.com/aVNcrnPikR0kyHiK3WWkGCjxnk4

Comment: @Omnifarious, nice, much better indeed :) Yours should be the accepted answer...

Comment: @TonvandenHeuvel - Because of the kind of person I am, I made a version that uses `::std::swap` to put the elements in place, so it should even now work on vectors of `unique_ptr`. :-)

Comment: @TonvandenHeuvel - My version stays the fastest up to very large N. Interesting: https://pastebin.com/EWNTUkdf

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 improvements for you:

- You can change your `count` to start at `g1.begin() + i`, everything before was handled by the previous iterations of the loop.
- You can change the if to `== 2` instead of `> 1`, so it will add numbers only once, independent of the occurences. If a number is 5 times in the vector, the first 3 will be ignored, the 4th will make it into the new vector and the 5th will be ignored again. So you can remove the `erase` of the duplicates

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector <int> g1 = {1,1,2,3,3,1,4};
    vector <int> g2;

    for(int i = 0; i < g1.size(); i++)
    {
      if(count(g1.begin() + i, g1.end(), g1[i]) == 2)
        g2.push_back(g1[i]);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < g2.size(); i++)
    {
      cout << g2[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll borrow a principal from Python which is excellent for such operations -

You can use a dictionary where the dictionary-key is the item in the vector and the dictionary-value is the count (start with 1 and increase by one every time you encounter a value that is already in the dictionary).

afterward, create a new vector (or clear the original) with only the dictionary keys that are larger than 1.

Look up in google - std::map

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In general, that task got complexity about  O(n*n), that's why it appears slow. Does it have to be a vector? Is that a restriction? Must it be ordered? If not, it better to actually store values as `std::map`, which eliminates doubles when populated, or as a `std::multimap` if presence of doubles matters.